# Overwrite values every time vs query to see if value has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a column that I would like to update only if the value I pass in to a stored procedure is different than the value in the column. It happens to be an NVARCHAR(255) column, if that matters.

What are the pros and cons of writing this value every time? What are the pros and cons of checking the value first and writing only if what I have passed in is different than what is in the database?

My simplified example where I'm doing a comparison before writing:

```
-- @URL and @ContentName are parameters of the sproc    

SET @ExistingURL =
    (SELECT TOP 1 C.URL
    FROM Content C
    WHERE ContentName = @ContentName)

-- update only if the parameter and existing value are different
IF(@ExistingURL != @URL)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Content
    SET URL = @URL
    WHERE ContentName = @ContentName
END
```

Comment: Well you could test the performance difference on your schema and hardware and with your workload to get an idea if the check is worth it. If you're updating other columns, and depending on the size of the row and/or the presence of a clustered index, I really doubt it will be. (There are a lot of variables.)

Comment: Do you know before you call the sproc if the value has changed or do you have to rely on the database? If your application code can track the change then it becomes a moot point.

Comment: @Mike Unless the application is doing pessimistic locking on the row, how could it track the change? Any other user may have modified it in the meantime. Also I am not convinced there is only a single value being passed into the procedure - what if three different columns need to be updated? I realize the question says "a column" but that is typically for simplification purposes.

Comment: If multiple users can change the data then you can't really let the application do it (not easily anyway). I was thinking more of a scenario where you could guarantee only the current thread was changing it.  In those cases though I've passed a bit flag for each column into the sproc. It does get cumbersome though.

Comment: @MikeParkhill and did you find a significant performance advantage in relying on the BIT columns instead of just updating all the columns? I suspect you would only see a noticeable difference in the case where all the BIT columns were false and no update had to be performed. In which case you didn't necessarily need to call the stored procedure at all.

Comment: It was faster compared to checking the data in the table before doing the update, but as you suggest, it was virtually the same as blindly updating.

Comment: @MrBoJangles can you please update the question to indicate whether you are really talking about updating ***a single column*** (which you can handle with a simple where clause) or if you are really talking about updating ***multiple columns***, any/all/none of which might have changed? A sample update statement you are currently running would be useful as well.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I have included a snippet which should answer your questions, and feel free to simplify the example. If it can be done in two lines instead of ten, all the better.

Comment: I simplified my example, plus there was an error in the query which I fixed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple pattern to solve this problem:

```
update my_table set
my_col = 'newValue'
where id = 'someKey'
and my_col != 'newValue';
```

This query has the performance of an indexed read, and importantly locks no rows, if the value doesn't need updating.

Only if the value needs updating does the where clause hit a row and lock it (albeit briefly) for update.

You can extend this to handle multiple columns using the same logic:

```
update my_table set
my_col1 = 'newValue1',
my_col2 = 'newValue2'
where id = 'someKey'
and (my_col1 != 'newValue1'
    or my_col2 != 'newValue2');
```

Comment: So, to summarize, the key to the answer is in the lock! The key is in the lock, ha, I slay me! Thanks, though.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because as I understand it, writes (because of locks) are generally more expensive than reads, which is the principle at work here. And you have a nice succinct example of an `update` with a `where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your query could be re-written as follows, without the need to put anything into a local variable.

```
UPDATE dbo.Content
  SET URL = @URL
  WHERE ContentName = @ContentName
  AND URL <> @URL;
```

Assuming that `ContentName` is unique, this will affect 0 or 1 rows. There is no need to make the logic more complex by pulling the check for the URL out into a separate query. The "write only if needed" part is taken care of by the `WHERE` clause.

Now, if you were to extend this to more than one column to update, what you're after isn't so simple (and I don't think it's worth it). Let's say, for example, that there was another column name `title`, and you had a variable coming in called `@title`. You predict that it will be smart to only update `URL` when it has changed, and only update `title` when it has changed. You could accomplish this in a couple of ways, in theory (and keep in mind, this all assumes that both the variables and the columns are not nullable - if they are, it doesn't change these approaches, just makes the syntax a little more daunting):

1. run two independent updates

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.Content SET URL = @URL
     WHERE ... -- actual where clause
     AND URL <> @URL;

   UPDATE dbo.Content SET title = @title
     WHERE ... -- same where clause
     AND title <> @title;
   ```
2. update conditionally

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.Content
     SET URL = CASE WHEN URL <> @URL THEN @URL ELSE URL END,
         title = CASE WHEN title <> @title THEN @title ELSE title END
   WHERE ... -- same where clause
   AND (URL <> @URL OR title <> @title);
   ```

I suspect that the latter won't perform any better than the more natural way to write this, since you're locking and writing to the row anyway (but I don't have any infallible proof of that other than the endorsement from Mike in the comments above):

```
UPDATE dbo.Content
  SET URL = @URL, title = @title
WHERE ... -- same where clause
AND (URL <> @URL OR title <> @title);
```

In other words, just update all values, regardless of which ones have actually changed.

Comment: +1  He was asking about a single column but that was not full story

Comment: Both of those bullet points have been addressed with my new example. The first was unnecessary to the example, and the second was just an error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Nominally a write is takes twice as long as a read.
A write will place a lock so it could potentially hold up reads.
It will place an entry in the transaction log.
What if you have a trigger on that value.

As a matter of practice I test for <> on any active database.

Taking a lock on every row could be a big hit if table is active.
Your update has to acquire the locks.
Other queries have to wait on your locks (unless they accept dirty reads).

If you are only actually updating 10% of the rows on a big active table and blinding updating all by not testing for <> then that is a big hit.

If you are updating 99% of the rows then you would take a small hit.
Testing for <> takes time.

By checking you could take a small hit but by not checking you (and others) could take a big hit.

Example update that checks for <>

```
Update [docSVsys] set [ftsStatus] = 5 where [ftsStaus] <> 5
```

The lock is on the entire row - not the individual column.
If you are updating more than 1 value then what still matters is % of rows.

```
Update [docSVsys] set [ftsStatus] = 5, [wfID] = 3 
where [ftsStatus] <> 5 or [wfID] <> 3
```

If only one of the values changed updating both is not not a hit as it had to acquire the update lock on the row.

Actual statement posted after many hours.

As Aaron stated the left joins do nothing.

As it stands that first query returns @URL or null.
And it is not based on ContentName.

So looking at

```
if(@ExistingURL != @URL)
```

That would only be true if no row in the table had that value.

A unique constraint would not be the same as it would only allow one null.

I am just surprised your question is not.  This update fails?

Comment: @AaronBertrand OK I agree a lock only goes to the row.  But the question is a column.  A is singular and column is singular.

Comment: OK, let's leave this as the simple answer. *shrug*